# error Cannot register 'com.temp.request.util.aspect.TraceLogger' because the type found with that name is not an aspect

Tags: java, aop, aspectj, spring-aop

I am using aspect oriented programming for separating logging concern in my project but while deployment I am getting following error in tomcat while deploying the application

> error Cannot register 'com.temp.request.util.aspect.TraceLogger'
>   because the type found with that name is not an aspect

TraceLogger class is as follows

```
package com.temp.request.util.aspect;

import java.util.Arrays;
import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

        public class TraceLogger {

            public Object logMethodEntryAndExit(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
                LOG.trace(joinPoint.getTarget().getClass().getName() + "." + joinPoint.getSignature().getName() + "() begins with " + Arrays.toString(joinPoint.getArgs()));
                Object result = joinPoint.proceed();
                LOG.trace(joinPoint.getTarget().getClass().getName() + "." + joinPoint.getSignature().getName() + "() ends with " + result);
                return result;
            }
        }
```

I have declared aspect and  TraceLogger bean in spring.xml file as follows

```
<bean id="TraceLogger" class="com.temp.request.util.aspect.TraceLogger" />

<aop:config>
        <aop:aspect id="methodLogger" ref="TraceLogger">
            <aop:pointcut id="logMethod"
                expression="execution(*  com.temp.request..*.*(..)) and !execution(*  com.temp.request.listener.*.*(..)) and !execution(*  com.temp.request.ws.*.*(..)) and !execution(* .util.*.*(..))" />
            <aop:around pointcut-ref="logMethod" method="logMethodEntryAndExit" />
        </aop:aspect>
</aop:config>
```

dependency declared in dependencies.gradle as follows

```
compile (
'org.aspectj:aspectjrt:1.8.4',
'org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:1.8.4',
'org.springframework:spring-instrument-tomcat:4.0.9.RELEASE'
)
```

Using load time weaving and specified following line in spring.xml as follows

```
 <context:load-time-weaver aspectj-weaving="on" weaver-class="org.springframework.instrument.classloading.tomcat.TomcatLoadTimeWeaver" />
```

Loading spring.xml by specifying contextConfigLocation in web.xml as follows

```
<context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Loading the aspect by specifying aspect name in aop.xml located in META-INF folder of my project as follows

```
<aspectj>
    <weaver options="-Xset:weaveJavaxPackages=true">        
        <include within="javax.jms.*"/>
    </weaver>
    <aspects>
        <aspect name="com.temp.request.util.aspect.TraceLogger" />
    </aspects>
</aspectj>
```

Why tomcat is not able to find  TraceLogger aspect while doing load time weaving ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are having a conceptual problem here:

- On the one hand you want to register a normal POJO class as a Spring AOP aspect via `<aop:config>`.
- On the other hand you want to use AspectJ load-time weaving via *aop.xml*.

Please note that AspectJ is not the same as Spring AOP, you should decide which of the two to use. I suggest to stick with Spring AOP for now and ditch the whole LTW stuff.

Looking at your Spring AOP aspect declaration `<aop:aspect id="methodLogger" ref="TraceLogger">` and the error message you get, I would think that you forgot to declare a Spring bean named "TraceLogger". If an aspect is not a Spring bean/component, you cannot use it as an aspect.

I warmly recommend to read the [Spring AOP manual](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#aop).

If you ever reach the limits of Spring AOP and want to explore the more powerful AspectJ there also is a chapter about how to configure [AspectJ via LTW](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#aop-using-aspectj). Please note that AspectJ is completely independent of Spring, you can use it inside of Spring projects or for any POJO or non-Spring container application you like, even for JVM languages other than Java.

Comment: I have not forgotten to declare spring bean TraceLogger. It is already there in my spring.xml . Updated the question

Comment: I am an AspectJ guy, not a Spring user. But AFAIK your way of declaring aspects in spring.xml is possible even without annotating them as `@Aspect` and `@Component` which nowadays is the standard way of doing it in connection with component scan. You can still try if these annotations help, but that is just a guess. Still I think you should get rid of the _aop.xml_ and  `<context:load-time-weaver ...> stuff. What is your goal anyway? To intercept Spring components or also non-Spring stuff?

Comment: In project this line is present in spring.xml  <tx:annotation-driven mode="aspectj" transaction-manager="transactionManager"/> so I guess load time weaving is used for transaction management

Comment: why it is giving this error even though I have specified TraceLogger as a bean in spring.xml? Should I include @Aspect annotation over TraceLogger class?

Comment: You could give it a try with `@Aspect`, just a shot into the blue to see if you get lucky. Otherwise, the easiest would be to distill your problem down into an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) reproducing the problematic behaviour and posting it on GitHub, then others could take a look.

Comment: BTW, you still have `<aspect name="com.temp.request.util.aspect.TraceLogger" />` in your _aop.xml_. You say AspectJ is only used for transactions, so why do you redeclare the aspect meant for Spring AOP inside _aop.xml_? Remove that line or the whole _aop.xml_ and see what happens.

Comment: Receiving javax.* types are not being woven because the weaver option '-Xset:weaveJavaxPackages=true' has not been specified warning once I remove aop.xml file

Comment: As well as receiving   error can't determine implemented interfaces of missing type javax.jms.Destination
when weaving type org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate